# Differences between anonymous and non-anonymous hyperlinks in Sphinx

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

In one of my Sphinx files, I have this :

```
.. _pyjnius:

Pyjnius
=======

When running on Android, a version of the `Pyjnius <https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/>`_
library is available. This allows advanced creators to call into the Android
libraries.
```

It seems to compile just how I want it to, but I get a warning saying that `WARNING: Duplicate explicit target name: "pyjnius"`. I got to [this issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3921), advising to end the link with two underscores rather than one, and that it's called an anonymous link. It's not the exact same problem: in the issue there's two links with the same name, and in my case there's only one link, but I tried the solution and it works.

What are the differences between  `` `this <link>`_ `` and  `` `that <link>`__ ``, aka between anonymous and non-anonymous links ? What would happen if I convert all my external hyperlinks to the double-underscore syntax ?

Comment: The question to yourself is why you wanted to use the same target name for different things (a header link and an external link). Try to use different target names for different things, and also separate the links and their target definitions https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#hyperlinks so that you share the same target everywhere and never hit this warning again.

Comment: @LexLi what are you calling a "target" ? The readthedocs link ? There's only one (external) link in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the differences between  (...) between anonymous and non-anonymous link

A [reference name](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#reference-names) is created when you declare a [hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets). But if the target is anonymous the name isn't used to match the reference to its target. The following quote from the docs sums it up:

> [Anonymous Hyperlinks](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#anonymous-hyperlinks)
>
> The reference name of the reference is not used to match the reference to its target. **Instead, the order of anonymous hyperlink references and targets within the document is significant**: the first anonymous reference will link to the first anonymous target. **The number of anonymous hyperlink references in a document must match the number of anonymous targets.**

Now the second part of the question that was embedded in the same sentence:

> What are the differences between    `` `this <link>`_ `` and   `` `that <link>`__ ``

If you read the reStructuredText specification carefully, no clear example of the concise   `` `Title <Link>`_ `` syntax is given, but it's an external hyperlink target (because the URL points to the exterior of your documentation). What happens is that the `Title` acts as the reference name for the target, hence the verbatim error: *"Duplicate explicit **target name**"*.

Making the declaration of the hyperlink target anonymous by using the double underscore `__` causes `Title` not to be used as the target name, thus there's no longer a duplicate target name because order of declaration is used to match the anonymous target to the `link`.

In conclusion:

> and in my case there's only one link

Yes, but what the error message is saying is that there's a  *"Duplicate explicit target name"* the problem is that `Pyjnius` is declared as a target once above the section, and again explicitly as the title (acting as target name) in the link using the shortened syntax.

Also note that the reference names (the target, or title) is normalized and thus case insensitive. Thus in your example the name `Pyjnius <URL>` ends up being normalized to `pyjnius` which is the same target name above the section.

> [Reference Names](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#reference-names)
>
> - case is normalized (all alphabetic characters are converted to lowercase).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! So, if I 1) keep only using inline syntax for hyperlinks and 2) switch them *all* to anonymous double-underscore syntax, it would work the same as before ?

Comment: @Gouvernathor yes, if you keep the external links as anonymous and the internal links as named it will work (and you get to always use the shortened syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The given example actually defines the reference name "pyjnius" **3 times**:

- The "explicit hyperlink target" syntax `.. _pyjnius:` makes the next element an explicit target named "pyjnius".
- By default, every section heading is also an "[implicit hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets)".¹
- The hyperlink with embedded target `Pyjnius <https:…>_` is a shorthand for both, a hyperlink reference and an explicit, named hyperlink target.

By default, explicit hyperlink targets silently override implicit ones. However the two external targets clash: Beeing "at the same level", Docutils/Sphinx does not know what to use as target, should the simple hyperlink reference `pyjnius_` occur somewhere else in the document.

¹The explicit target replicating the section title is superfluous unless you use the same (sub)section title again in another (sub)section and want to disambiguate which one should be the target to equally named links.)